# Where has the EE2 documentation gone?

Tags: ee2

I can't find the EE2 user guide on the web. Several google snippets have "Expression Engine 2 user guide" supposedly on a page on the Ellislabs site but when I click them I don't see the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr Armitage is kindly hosting them: http://ee2docs.com/

Comment: You can also download them using the dropdown at the rop right of https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/

Answer (score 3):

They are still available here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/